# Modify tex file to move chapter headers upper

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting

I'd like to modify this code to make chapter titles appear uppper, so more text can get into the first chapter page and modifiy the TOC adding dots from the title to the page number. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\title{Microcuentos 1}
\author{Juanjo Conti}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Justificación de los cuentos cortos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Justificación de los cuentos cortos}

Muchos de los cuentos que escribo son cortos. Esta cuestión anatómica de la literatura tiene una gran ventaja: si el cuento es bueno, en pocas líneas puede sacarte una sonrisa o provocarte un pensamiento profundo. Si el cuento es malo, no importa, en pocos segundos más termina.

Esta teoría, al igual que los cuentos cortos, goza de esta ventaja.


\part*{Sueños}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Sueños}

\chapter*{Los eternos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Los eternos}

La primera vez que nos tocamos fue hace más de quinientos años en una playa en San Salvador, aunque ella llamaba al lugar Guanahaní. Se ocultó detrás de unas rocas sobre la arena cuando vio que una multitud de seres extraños salíamos del agua gritan y empujándonos. Los temores del viaje, las enfermedades, el hambre y el recuerdo de los que habíamos dejado en el mar fueron un catalizador que entró en acción cuando uno de los nosotros gritó “Tierra”.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the changes in the ToC you can use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and redefine `\cftchapleader`; to change the chapter heading formatting, to need to redefine `\DOTI` and `\DOTSI` (as implemented for the `Lenny` style) to reduce the spacing after the titles; for the space before the titles, you can patch `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`; a little example (feel free to make the adjustments to the lengths that best suit your needs):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

% change the space before the titles
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{0pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{0pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

% change the space after the titles
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \raggedright
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10pt}% original: 40pt
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \raggedright
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10pt}% original: 40pt

\title{Microcuentos 1}
\author{Juanjo Conti}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Justificación de los cuentos cortos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Justificación de los cuentos cortos}

Muchos de los cuentos que escribo son cortos. Esta cuestión anatómica de la literatura tiene una gran ventaja: si el cuento es bueno, en pocas líneas puede sacarte una sonrisa o provocarte un pensamiento profundo. Si el cuento es malo, no importa, en pocos segundos más termina.

Esta teoría, al igual que los cuentos cortos, goza de esta ventaja.


\part*{Sueños}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Sueños}

\chapter*{Los eternos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Los eternos}

La primera vez que nos tocamos fue hace más de quinientos años en una playa en San Salvador, aunque ella llamaba al lugar Guanahaní. Se ocultó detrás de unas rocas sobre la arena cuando vio que una multitud de seres extraños salíamos del agua gritan y empujándonos. Los temores del viaje, las enfermedades, el hambre y el recuerdo de los que habíamos dejado en el mar fueron un catalizador que entró en acción cuando uno de los nosotros gritó “Tierra”.

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

and one from the firs chapter:

[image]

If the part entries in the ToC must also have the dot leaders, it's enough to add

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

to the code above.